# Flash object in FireFox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, speech-recognition, voice, voice-recognition

I want to implement a voice recognition in my FireFox extension. I trying with http://www.speechapi.com/ but the extension never shows me the flash object in the sidebar panel. ¿Is possible add a flash object in a firefox extension to get acces to the microphone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. SpeechAPI is not for you.

You can use embedded speech recognizer in your extension just by recording sound and calling CMUSphinx core

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net